# How can I format my fully encrypted drive through BusyBox?

Tags: disk-management, format

Something went wrong with my installation of elementary OS and I don't have a second operating system on this laptop. I have Kali Linux ready to install on a usb drive, but the only problem is my entire hard drive is encrypted with LUKS. Now, because my OS is jacked up, it launches me directly to BusyBox v1.21.1. How can I format the hard drive through the shell and be done with this whole problem?

Note. I only have a select number of commands to choose from. It doesnt appear to be a standard shell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not elementary specific. Try to ask over there at unix.stackexchange.com